# put i18next value inside variable JS

Tags: javascript, html, i18next

I have a JS code that changes the text after some time and I want to use i18next translations in that to make the words "performance, flexibility" etc.. be in more than 1 language. the idea I had to solve this was putting the i18next value inside a variable and substitue the words in the JS code with the variables. but I don't know how to use i18next to put his translated words inside a variable, if someone could help me I would be very grateful!

Json files

en-US

```
"index" : {
    "performance" : " performance",
    "flexibility" : "flexibility"
}
```

pt-PT

```
"index" : {
    "performance" : " Desempenho",
    "flexibility" : "Flexibilidade"
}
```

JS code

```js
var typed1 = new Typed('#typed1', {
    strings: ["performance", "flexibility", "scalability."],
    typeSpeed: 50,
    backSpeed: 20,
    smartBackspace: true,
    loop: true
});
var typed1 = new Typed('#typed2', {
    strings: ["Protection", "Sophisticated", "Flexibility"],
    typeSpeed: 100,
    backSpeed: 50,
    smartBackspace: true,
    loop: true
});
```

Comment: Can you please describe better what you actually like to achieve? Maybe you just need to use the interpolation feature? https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation

Comment: Basically i want to translate the words in the JS code, my HTML that display this 3 words is this:

 <div class="heading mergecolor">Dedicated <br>Server with <br><span id="typed1"></span></div>

i tried this but didn't work:

var test = i18next.t('index.performance');
var typed1 = new Typed('#typed1', {
    strings: [test, "flexibility", "scalability."],
    typeSpeed: 50,
    backSpeed: 20,
    smartBackspace: true,
    loop: true
});
I just need to know how i can put the value of the i18next inside a var for when i change the language the var receives the other value

Comment: Have you tried the Trans component? https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component

Comment: Yeah, but i didn't understood how i could use this to solve my problem :/ if you could help me i would be very very grateful